# NServiceBus 3.2 - NullReferenceException at NServiceBus.Timeout.Core.TimeoutRunner.CacheExistingTimeouts()

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus3

A big thank-you to Andreas in helping my previous NSB 3.2 issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904857/nservicebus-endpoints-looking-for-ravendb-for-timeouts-after-upgrading-3-0-3). After implementing that change I now have a FATAL exception during startup of each service.

Each service (in a class implementing IWantCustomInitialisation) is configured as follows;

```
        Configure.With()
            .DBSubcriptionStorage()
            .Sagas()
            .NHibernateSagaPersister()
            .NHibernateUnitOfWork()
            .DisableSecondLevelRetries()                      
            .DisableTimeoutManager();
```

This is in the log during startup:

```
2012-06-08 21:49:46,946 [4] INFO  NServiceBus.Host - Going to activate profile: NServiceBus.PerformanceCounters, NServiceBus.Host, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c
2012-06-08 21:49:46,947 [4] INFO  NServiceBus.Host - Going to activate profile: NServiceBus.Production, NServiceBus.Host, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c
2012-06-08 21:49:46,947 [4] INFO  NServiceBus.Host - Going to activate profile: NServiceBus.PerformanceCounters, NServiceBus.Host, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c
2012-06-08 21:49:46,962 [4] DEBUG NServiceBus.Host - Activating profile handler: NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.Profiles.Handlers.PerformanceCountersProfileHandler, NServiceBus.Host, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c
2012-06-08 21:49:46,963 [4] DEBUG NServiceBus.Host - Activating profile handler: NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.Profiles.Handlers.ProductionProfileHandler, NServiceBus.Host, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c
2012-06-08 21:49:52,063 [4] FATAL NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at NServiceBus.Timeout.Core.TimeoutRunner.CacheExistingTimeouts()
 at NServiceBus.Timeout.Core.TimeoutRunner.Run()
 at NServiceBus.Unicast.Config.StartupRunners.<Run>b__5(IWantToRunWhenTheBusStarts r)
 at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
 at NServiceBus.Unicast.Config.StartupRunners.<Run>b__4(Object obj, EventArgs ev)
 at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.NServiceBus.IStartableBus.Start(Action startupAction)
 at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.NServiceBus.IStartableBus.Start()
 at NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost.Start() in d:\BuildAgent-03\work\nsb.master22\src\hosting\NServiceBus.Hosting\GenericHost.cs:line 32
```

Comment: Could be a bug, I'll get back to you!

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce, can you verify that you have put that code on the same class as the one that implements IConfigureThisEndpoint?